# Porqué un KeyListener en JtextArea no funciona si incluyo JButton?

Tags: java, textarea

Tengo un JFrame que contiene dos componentes; un JButton y un JTextarea. El JTextarea tiene un KeyListener. Sí solo tengo habilitado el JTextarea funciona bien, es decir, al iniciar el programa, si pulso una tecla se refleja correctamente la implementación de los métodos de KeyListener. Sin embargo si y habilito ambos componentes, botón y textarea, al pulsar una tecla, no se imprime nada (settext en el área) en mi Textarea. Si se cambia el button a true, la aplicación no recoge las pulsaciones mientras que si está en false funciona bien

```
 package fig3637;


 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class KeyDemoFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener 
 {
 private String line1 = ""; // first line of textarea
 private String line2 = ""; // second line of textarea
 private String line3 = ""; // third line of textarea
 private JTextArea textArea; // textarea to display output
 private JButton button; 
 Color bc;

// KeyDemoFrame constructor
public KeyDemoFrame()
{
  super("Demonstrating Keystroke Events");
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  textArea = new JTextArea(10, 15); // set up JTextArea
  textArea.setText("Press any key on the keyboard...");
  textArea.setEnabled(false);
  textArea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  button=new JButton("button");
  bc=button.getBackground();

  addKeyListener(this); // allow frame to process key events
  add(textArea); // add textarea to JFrameç

  add(button);
  button.setEnabled(false);//CAMBIANDO AQUI A TRUE SE VE LA DIFERENCIA


  } 

  // handle press of any key
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
  {
  line1 = String.format("Key pressed: %s", 
    KeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode())); // show pressed key
  setLines2and3(event); // set output lines two and three

  button.setBackground(Color.orange);
  }

  // handle release of any key
 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
 {
  line1 = String.format("Key released: %s",
     KeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode())); // show released key
  setLines2and3(event); // set output lines two and three
  button.setBackground(bc);
 }

 // handle press of an action key
 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
 {
  line1 = String.format("Key typed: %s", event.getKeyChar());
  setLines2and3(event); // set output lines two and three
 }
 // set second and third lines of output

 private void setLines2and3(KeyEvent event)
 {
  line2 = String.format("This key is %san action key", 
     (event.isActionKey() ? "" : "not "));

  String temp = KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(event.getModifiers());

  line3 = String.format("Modifier keys pressed: %s", 
     (temp.equals("") ? "none" : temp)); // output modifiers

  textArea.setText(String.format("%s\n%s\n%s\n", 
     line1, line2, line3)); // output three lines of text
 }
} // end class KeyDemoFrame
```

Comment: en lugar de setText() prueba con el metodo appen(), ya que el metodo setText borra lo que escribiste antes

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz esto que dices me sirve pero no responde a mi pregunta. Tengo que deshabilitar el button para que el textarea recoja los keylistener, sino no los recoge

Comment: Tendria que ver el codigo, sino estaria adivinando, sube el codigo

Comment: Este código es un ejemplo del Deitel pero refleja lo que le sucede al programa que realizo. En el constructor al añadir el botón , cambia a true o false e inicializa

Comment: Despues de batallar harto, encontre el problema. Lo que pasa es que al agregar el boton la ventana pierde el foco. Por lo tanto depues que llames al metodo setVisible() para ver la ventana, llama al metodo requestFocus() de la ventana o JFrame

Comment: No lo veo: 
      add(button);
      button.setEnabled(true);
      textArea.requestFocus(); pero siguie sin ir

Comment: He probado setfocus en el Button a false y bueno, funciona bien pero hace que el button no sea focuseable con lo que no se si me servirá. Habrá que seguir testeando. Gracias

Comment: Es que es una mala idea poner el addKeyListener en la ventana, seria mejor ponerll en una JComponente

Comment: Tienes la clase donde esta el metodo main???

Comment: Probaré a rehacer mi programa insertando el KeyListener en ambos, Panel y frame y veré resultados